# Gradle error Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

When i run the command

```
ionic cordova build android
```

After I run the above command I have the following result and tried to solve it in several ways but nothing that works.

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Sumburane\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
Subproject Path: CordovaLib

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

More details on my application follow the details of my ionic info

**DO NOT NEDD TO READ**
More details on my application follow the details of my ionic info.
About the details I've explained above now I'm just writing to stop having this error **It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.** when editing this question and lots of apologies for it.

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 (C:\Users\Sumburane\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.5
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2

Capacitor:

   capacitor (Capacitor CLI) : 1.0.0-beta.24
   @capacitor/core           : 1.0.0-beta.24

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.4.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.1, (and 5 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v8.9.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Comment: Could you post this error message and info as text?

Comment: yes for sure. I did it can you see now?